# How to import a component that is rendered in another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, components, react-modal

I have a *form component* rendered in a component, *component1*, and I want to use it in another component, *component2*, but I want to use it with all the functionality that it has inside *component1*. How can I do this? I tried exporting it from inside *component1* but it didn't work.

Here is where the form component is rendered in *component1*:

```
return (
  <OutsideClickHandler onOutsideClick={this.handleBlur}>
    
     //some not important code was here

      <div
        id={id}
        className={popupClasses}
        ref={node => {
          this.filterContent = node;
        }}
        style={contentStyle}
      >
        {this.state.isOpen ? (
          <FilterForm                           // this FilterFrom I want to export into another component
            id={`${id}.form`}
            paddingClasses={popupSizeClasses}
            showAsPopup
            contentPlacementOffset={contentPlacementOffset}
            initialValues={initialValues}
            keepDirtyOnReinitialize={keepDirtyOnReinitialize}
            onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            onCancel={this.handleCancel}
            onClear={this.handleClear}
          >
            {children}
          </FilterForm>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  </OutsideClickHandler>
);
```

}
}

Here is where I want to import and use the *form component*:

```
return (
  <div className={classes}>
   
     //some not important code was here
         
    <ModalInMobile
      id="SearchFiltersMobile.filters"
      isModalOpenOnMobile={this.state.isFiltersOpenOnMobile}
      onClose={this.cancelFilters}
      showAsModalMaxWidth={showAsModalMaxWidth}
      onManageDisableScrolling={onManageDisableScrolling}
      containerClassName={css.modalContainer}
      closeButtonMessage={modalCloseButtonMessage}
    >
      
            //here I want to import and use the *form component*


    </ModalInMobile>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`FilterForm` job is to perform certain logics and display some elements in the DOM, based on its props and states (Just like how system works, you can have a car parked or have a car running both are the same system but with different inputs and states). So you already have your component. If you mean that attributes like `popupSizeClasses`, `contentPlacementOffset`, `keepDirtyOnReinitialize`, .... are shared between component1 and component2, you can make a wrapper around `FilterForm` with those values passed to `FilterForm`. So you would render `FilterFormWrapper` component instead.

But make sure that some props like `onCancel` (which is equal to `this.handleCancel`) are independent and does not have any dependency (state or props) to component1, so you can extract them.